# Make calls from my computer, not using VoIP

Tags: android, osx, phone, integrations

I am looking for a way to make phone calls from my computer. I have an android phone and a Mac computer. I'd like my mac to remotely control my phone, make the call, receive the call's input audio to my Mac's speakers, and send my voice through my Mac's mic into the call.

Basically, something like messages.google.com, which just lets me send and receive my regular texts from my computer, but for calls.

I don't want to use VoIP, and I don't want to create a new number. I just want to be able to make regular calls from my computer if my phone is in another room. If a bluetooth or wifi connection is required, that is fine.

Comment: I know I'm in the minority, but I think macs are the better computer and androids are the better smartphone. In both cases, I chose the one that's easiest to customize and configure and develop software on.

Answer (score 0):

[Someone](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/khisv0/comment/gvydn65/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) on Reddit mentioned [Connecton](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/connecton/id1497000705?mt=12) on the App Store. I haven't personally tried it, but I will. I'll update when done.

##### –> UPDATE

Connecton requires a monthly or yearly fee; I don't think I'm paying it right now because I can already do this with my iPhone. I'll update agin if I decide to pay.